# Spring JSON and 406 HTTP error

Tags: jquery, json, spring, jackson

i find a lot of questions about this problem but i did not solve...
I have this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/testInit")
public @ResponseBody Output test() throws Exception {
    return new Output(true);
}
```

and i had jackson libreary to classpath,  into applicationContext but i still get 406 error with this jquery call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/testInit",
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using jackson-all.1.9.0.jar instead of jackson 2 libraries.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the jars and also add `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` and `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` to DispatcherServlet-servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
```

like shown above.

Answer (score 0):

The `406 Not Acceptable` response is used when the client has requested a content type that the server cannot return. In other words, your client (e.g. the web browser) is sending an `Accept` header that does not match the server's capabilities.

I'm guessing that the jQuery Ajax method uses the `dataType` field when setting the `Accept` header. `json` is not a well-known content type - but `application/json` is.

Try replacing `dataType: "json"` with `dataType: "application/json"`.

Comment: This is the header catch with firebug: Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get mine to work was upgrade spring to 3.1 and add a produces to the request mapping.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/{myVar}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public MyObject get(
        @PathVariable String myVar) {
```

None of the other solutions worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, finally tracked down to not having any getters on the class I was using.

i.e. this caused a 406

```
public static class Pojo {
    private int x;
    public Pojo(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

But this didn't

```
public static class Pojo {
    private int x;
    public Pojo(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Yes I was using a class called Pojo :) - I was just doing a dummy example to check Jackson was working in my new setup